# Limiting an object to one ownership ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parent-child, parent, belongs-to

I have a `Flag` model that has the possibility of belonging to a `Topic`, `Post`, or `Review`. With that being said the `Flag` model has all three of their corresponding IDs.

```
class Flag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :review
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags
end
```

When it comes down to flagging for, let's say, a post how do I ensure that no other ID (`topic_id`, `review_id`) can exist thereafter? I thought of creating specific flag models for each of the three but that route seems too repetitive. Would a model validation be my only sensible choice? If so what would it look like? More importantly am I going about this association setup in the right way?

Comment: Sounds like you want the belongs_to relationship to be polymorphic.   See 2.9 of the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html if you're not familiar with that...

Comment: Add a custom validation for every association and check if another associations are presented. If they are presented add a validation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)?

Try with:

```
class Flag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flaggable, polymorphic: true
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags, as: :flaggable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags, as: :flaggable
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flags, as: :flaggable
end


class UpdateAssociationsOnFlags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index  :flags, :topic_id
    remove_column :flags, :topic_id

    remove_index  :flags, :post_id
    remove_column :flags, :post_id

    remove_index  :flags, :review_id
    remove_column :flags, :review_id


    add_column :flags, :flaggable_id, :integer
    add_column :flags, :flaggable_type, :string

    add_index :flags, :flaggable_id
  end
end
```

### Edit, in reply to the question author's comment:

You can just add a different association:

```
class Flag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flaggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :reporter, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :reporter_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reported_flags, class_name: 'Flag', foreign_key: :reporter_id
end

class AddUserForeignKeyToFlags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :flags, :reporter_id, :integer
    add_index :flags, :reporter_id
  end
end
```

Comment: For the sake of argument what if there was an instance where a flag could only belong to 1 of the 3 **AND** a `User` (where the user is the flag's *reporter*). How would you go about in referring to the `user` or `post` since they're now both `flaggable`? Originally it would be `@flag.user` or `@flag.post`. How is it written using this convention?

Comment: This solution couldn't have come at a better time. Thanks so much for your help! +1.